# Android: How to show Interstitial ad After Coming Back from Play store more apps Intent?

Tags: android, interstitial, onbackpressed

I have a button in my application with the name of "More Apps". After Clicking on that button user go to the play store . I want to show the interstitial ad when user press back at that time.

Answer (score 1):

First create a flag

```
boolean enableAd = false;
```

then in your button click enable the flag

```
moreApps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            enabledAd = true;
            goToPlayStore();
        }
    });
```

now in your *onResume()*(this function will be called by default when you come back from play store) function check whether the flag is set or not to show your ad.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(enabledAd) {
        showYourAd();
        enableAd=false;
    }
}
```